# How can I convert the private key stored in HSM to SignedXml.SigningKey in C#

Tags: c#, private-key, pkcs#11, xml-signature, pkcs11interop

I'm trying to implement some demo of XML signing with a certificate which stored in the HSM.

I found some interesting example from this link:
[Sign XML Document with X509Certificate2](http://www.asptricks.net/2015/09/sign-xmldocument-with-x509certificate2.html) and modified it to using certificate and key inside the HSM with PKCS11Interop wrapper.

But anyone could give me a suggestion or example to **convert ObjectHandle privateKey from HSM to SignedXML.SigningKey**

```
private static void SignXmlWithCertificate(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 cert, Session session, String alias)
        {
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

            List<ObjectAttribute> template = new List<ObjectAttribute>();
            template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY));
            template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_RSA));
            template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_LABEL, alias));
            List<ObjectHandle> foundObjects = session.FindAllObjects(template);
            ObjectHandle privateKey = foundObjects[0];

            signedXml.SigningKey = privateKey; //Here is where I stuck.
```

In the example from above external link. They using a certificate which combined private key. Then they can use like this.

```
signedXml.SigningKey = cert.PrivateKey;
```

But the certificate that I'm using haven't content of private key inside. Please give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement custom class inherited from [System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml(v=vs.110).aspx) like this

```
public class CustomSignedXml: SignedXml
    {
    public CustomSignedXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc):base(xmlDoc)
    {
    }
    internal void ComputeSignature(ISignerProvider signerProvider)
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof (SignedXml).GetMethod("BuildDigestedReferences",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        methodInfo.Invoke(this, null);
        SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = XmlDsigRSASHA1Url;
        // See if there is a signature description class defined in the Config file
        SignatureDescription signatureDescription =
            CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(SignedInfo.SignatureMethod) as SignatureDescription;
        if (signatureDescription == null)
            throw new CryptographicException("Cryptography_Xml_SignatureDescriptionNotCreated");

        var hashAlg = signatureDescription.CreateDigest();
        if (hashAlg == null)
            throw new CryptographicException("Cryptography_Xml_CreateHashAlgorithmFailed");
        var methodInfo2 = typeof (SignedXml).GetMethod("GetC14NDigest", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var hashvalue = (byte[]) methodInfo2.Invoke(this, new object[] {hashAlg});

        m_signature.SignatureValue = signerProvider.Sign(hashvalue);
    }
}
```

and then you need to create interface like this

```
public interface ISignerProvider
{
    byte[] Sign(byte[] data);
}
```

then implement it by [Pkcs11Interop](https://www.pkcs11interop.net/) like this

```
    public class Pkcs11SignerProvider : ISignerProvider
{
    private string _thumbprint;
    public string DllPath { get; set; }
    public string TokenSerial { get; set; }
    public string TokenPin { get; set; }
    public string PrivateKeyLabel { get; set; }

    public Pkcs11SignerProvider(string dllPath, string tokenSerial, string tokenPin, string privateKeyLabel)
    {
        DllPath = dllPath;
        TokenSerial = tokenSerial;
        TokenPin = tokenPin;
        PrivateKeyLabel = privateKeyLabel;
    }

    public byte[] Sign(byte[] data)
    {
        using (var pkcs11 = new Pkcs11(DllPath, AppType.SingleThreaded))
        {

            var slots = pkcs11.GetSlotList(SlotsType.WithTokenPresent);
            var slot = slots.FirstOrDefault(slot1 => slot1.GetTokenInfo().SerialNumber == TokenSerial);
            if (slot == null)
                throw new Exception("there is no token with serial " + TokenSerial);
            using (var session = slot.OpenSession(SessionType.ReadOnly))
            {
                session.Login(CKU.CKU_USER, TokenPin);

                var searchTemplate = new List<ObjectAttribute>
                {
                    new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY),
                    new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_RSA)
                };
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PrivateKeyLabel))
                    searchTemplate.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_LABEL, PrivateKeyLabel));

                var foundObjects = session.FindAllObjects(searchTemplate);
                var privateKey = foundObjects.FirstOrDefault();

                using (var mechanism = new Mechanism(CKM.CKM_RSA_PKCS))
                {
                    return session.Sign(mechanism, privateKey, data);
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

then call this method to sign xml

```
public static void Sign(XmlDocument xmlDoc, ISignerProvider signerProvider)
    {
        if (xmlDoc == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("xmlDoc");
        if (xmlDoc.DocumentElement == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("xmlDoc.DocumentElement");
        var signedXml = new CustomSignedXml(xmlDoc);
        var reference = new Reference { Uri = "" };
        var env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(env);
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);
        signedXml.ComputeSignature(signerProvider);
        var xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
    }
```

and this code to verify

```
        public static bool Verify(XmlDocument document, X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (document == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Doc");
        if (certificate == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Key");

        // Create a new SignedXml object and pass it
        // the XML document class.
        var signedXml = new SignedXml(document);

        // Find the "Signature" node and create a new
        // XmlNodeList object.
        var nodeList = document.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

        // Throw an exception if no signature was found.
        if (nodeList.Count <= 0)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: No Signature was found in the document.");
        }

        // This example only supports one signature for
        // the entire XML document.  Throw an exception 
        // if more than one signature was found.
        if (nodeList.Count >= 2)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: More that one signature was found for the document.");
        }

        // Load the first <signature> node.  
        signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

        return signedXml.CheckSignature(certificate, true);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Gholamreza,

I really appreciate your kindly help. I'll try it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement custom class inherited from [`System.Security.Cryptography.RSA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03h9zcez(v=vs.110).aspx) class, use Pkcs11Interop in its implementation and then use instance of your custom class as a [`SigningKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.signingkey(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can implement it yourself or you can use [Pkcs11Interop.X509Store](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store) library which provides easy to use PKCS#11 based X.509 certificate store and contains [`Pkcs11RsaProvider`](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store/blob/0.1.0/src/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store/Pkcs11RsaProvider.cs) class inherited from [`System.Security.Cryptography.RSA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03h9zcez(v=vs.110).aspx) class. There's also a [code sample](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store/blob/0.1.0/src/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store.Tests/SignedXmlTest.cs) available which demonstrates its usage with [`SignedXml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: Hi Jariq,

You mean I need to create a new inherited class with all properties and methods like RSA class right? Where can I put the private key into it? Could you please guide me more or give some brief sample code.

Comment: @ktikar Yes you need to create inherited class - the most important part is to override `SignHash` method and implement it with Pkcs11Interop. I plan to release standalone library with such implementation but I am currently busy with other paid projects.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll try it.

Comment: @ktikar I have updated my answer with details about Pkcs11Interop.X509Store project. You might find it interesting.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you.